# is there any way in which i can get location without any package flutter?

Tags: flutter, permissions, geolocation, location

I want to get location and allow location permission in my flutter app
without using any plugin or location package. is there any way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if plugin can be created so why can't we create on over self?

Comment: you can    create android and ios method channel

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a plugin yourself that uses a platform channel in order to call native APIs. That essentially does the same as other plugins so there would be no difference between you making one on your own or using a prebuild one.

But If you still want to do it look at [How to make plugins in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) and [Writing platform specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-c-plus-plus-tab).

Comment: Actually reason behind creating custom things is to have more control
and lesser app size